# Linking framework, header not found

Tags: ios, xcode

I have one project which is using a few libraries. The libraries are installed with CocoaPods. In another project I have added the first project to so that it is the master project. When I run the master project, it shows that the headers cannot be found from the libraries that were installed by CocoaPods. I have added all paths to master project but it still can't find the headers in from the installed pods.

---

Xcode version: 9.2
This is my pod:

```
target 'XMPPNative' do
    use_frameworks!
    # 3.7 Stable Release
    pod 'XMPPFramework', '~> 3.7.0'
end
```

Comment: You should add the pods to the master project itself. When you include the subproject make sure you don't include the pods that are installed there.

Comment: I can't add pods to master project (means that I am not allow add pods to my master project). It is one of my limitation. any suggestion?

Comment: If that is the case then I would turn your subproject into a compiled framework then and add that to the master project. https://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios